# ImageView Pinch Scaling

Tags: android, image, android-imageview, android-gesture

Right now I have a layout that contains two imageviews, one in the background and one in the front that is a icon. Both of them will merge together as a single image and save it to sd card. The image of the icon can be move around before the user save it to sd card.

Now what i require is to allow the user to pinch the image of the icon so they could scale the image **evenly** without losing its proportion.

This is how i allow my icon image to move around in my onCreate class.

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    if (isImageMoving)
    {
        x = event.getRawX() - img_additionalImage.getWidth();
        y = event.getRawY() - img_additionalImage.getHeight();
        img_additionalImage.setX(x);
        img_additionalImage.setY(y);
    }
    break;
```

I want the user to freely scale the icon image to the desired size then let them save it to sd card.

Comment: you can resize the image 

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html#load-bitmap

Comment: thats not want i am trying to do. I am trying to allow the user to pinch the image to scale up/down

Comment: See this sample.. Its a complete solution https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView